# Pass return value back to loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested

I'm embarrassed to ask this but I'm a novice so here it goes...

I have an array of integers which I want to loop through and divide each integer by a divisor in another array.

```
integers = [50, 20, 18, 27, 19]
divisors = [2, 3, 2]
```

Loop through integers and divide by `divisors[0]`. Take resulting array and divide each integer by `divisors[1]`. Take resulting array and divide each integer by `divisors[2]`.

Pretty easy, I know, but I can't figure out how to pass the new array as an argument.

Here's what I have so far. I need to end up with an array with the length of 5 but I end up with one of 15.

```
const divide = function(arr) {
var result = []
for (i = 0; i < divisors.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        result.push(Math.floor(arr[j] / divisors[i]))
        // how do I pass "result" as new value for "arr"?
    }
  }
  return result
}
console.log(divide(integers))
```

In terms of big-O I know this isn't the most efficient way to solve this problem as the result would be O(n^2). But, like I said, I'm a novice.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want floats or integers as result? If integers, should the result be rounded down after every division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to iterate the divisors, and return a new array by `Array.map`ing the previous array:

```js
var integers = [50, 20, 18, 27, 19];
var divisors = [2, 3, 2];

var result = divisors.reduce(function(r, div) {
  return r.map(function(n) { // the new array after dividing each element by current divistor
    return n / div; 
  });
}, integers); // the initial array

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It all comes back to map and reduce. Thanks, Ori!

Comment: Welcome, but check out @fafl's simple & clever answer.

Comment: What would the big-O be on this solution?

Comment: It's O(n * m) - divisors * integers. @fafl's is O(n + m) which is much better.

Answer (score 2):

This works and runs in O(n+m):

```js
var integers = [50, 20, 18, 27, 19];
var divisors = [2, 3, 2];

// compute product of all divisors
var product = divisors.reduce((x, y) => x * y)

// map each integer to result of division, rounded down
var result = integers.map(i => Math.floor(i / product))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a quick code to :
first obtain expected result as an 2D array with nested **Array.map()**
second flat the 2D array into a flat array with **Array.reduce()**

```js
var integers = [50, 20, 18, 27, 19];
var divisors = [2, 3, 2];
var results = divisors.map(x => integers.map(y => Math.floor(y/x))).reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b));
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this can be done by a `.map()` and `.reduce()` hand to hand;

```js
var integers = [50, 20, 18, 27, 19],
    divisors = [2, 3, 2],
      result = integers.map(n => divisors.reduce((r,d) => r/d,n)) ;
console.log(result);
```